# Obtaining MLE of the parameter of exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

Let say I have a sample of size $n$ as $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$.

The sample points $X_i$ are integers, but each of them are actually integer ceiling of corresponding real number $\{Y_i\}$. For example if $Y_1 = 50.45$ then corresponding $X_1 = 51$.

Also $Y_i \sim \mathrm{exponential}\left(\lambda \right)$.

From the observed sample $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$, is it possible to obtain `MLE` of $\lambda$?

What will be the case if $X_i$ are actually integer floor of corresponding real number $\{Y_i\}$. For example if $Y_1 = 50.45$ then corresponding $X_1 = 50$?

Comment: This looks like homework. How does the question arise? 1. I presume $\lambda$ is intended to be the parameter for the rate parameterization rather than the scale-parameterization of the exponential, but you should make your parameterization explicit. 2. You can certainly get an MLE of $\lambda$ from the resulting distribution of the $X_i$; indeed you should be able to write the distribution down by inspection.  2. The question at the end is simply shifting the definition first $X$ variable down by 1; otherwise everything else is the same.

Comment: When the underlying distribution is $F(\ ;\theta),$ the likelihood of observing $\lceil x\rceil$ is $F(\lceil x\rceil;\theta)-F(\lceil x\rceil-1;\theta).$ That's still a simple function for Exponential distributions, so you ought to be able to obtain a solution in a tractable form.  Notice that $\lceil X\rceil$ has a Geometric distribution. The situation with the floor is identical because these distributions are continuous.

Comment: @Glen_b It is not a homework problem, but I am self studying the subject of statistics. So this question came to my mind as I am looking for a general approach for this type of problem. Regarding my last question, if I understood your comment, then you say that `ceiling(x-1) = floor(x)`. But while this is true for all non-integer, it may not be true if `x` is integer, right? But domain of `exponential distribution` also take integers as it's support takes entire non negative real line.

Comment: Although your distinction between $\lceil X-1\rceil$ and $\lfloor X\rfloor$ is correct, it is irrelevant when $X$ has zero chance of being an integer, which -- as I pointed out above -- is the case for any continuous random variable.  In other words, $\lceil X-1\rceil = \lfloor X\rfloor$ *almost surely* for such variables.